# Foundation left-menu pushes main section down

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to figure out how to make a left-menu with Foundation. All the tutorial I have read show how to make the menu, but since the examples consist only of a menu and nothing right of it, they do not help...

Here is what I have:

```
<ul class="four side-nav">
  <li><a ng-click="page = 1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 4">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The parameters content will be displayed in this block by Django-->
<div class="main-section" id="content">
{% block parameters %}

{% endblock %}
</div>
```

The left menu works well, but my main-section div is pushed under it instead of right of it. I'm probably just missing the class, but I found no full example of a simple main-content with a left-menu.

Thank you!

Edit:

Here is the css for side-nav. I'm using foundation.css and honestly I never really opened it.

```
.side-nav {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.875rem 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

And main-section isn't something that seem to actually exist in my css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without see your css(would be nice if you add it to see the real problem) I just can give you some general way to do what you want.

**1-** Float left the `.side-nav` and set margin to `main-section`:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side-nav {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: #44aac1;
  
   /*your side-nav style*/
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.875rem 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

.main-section {
    height: 300px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="four side-nav">
  <li><a ng-click="page = 1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 4">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The parameters content will be displayed in this block by Django-->
<div class="main-section" id="content">
    main section content
</div>
```

**2-** Floating both elements and set `width` to `main-section`:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side-nav {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: #44aac1;
  
   /*your side-nav style*/
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.875rem 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

.main-section {
    float: left; /*or rigth*/
    height: 300px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="four side-nav">
  <li><a ng-click="page = 1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 4">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The parameters content will be displayed in this block by Django-->
<div class="main-section" id="content">
    main section content
</div>
```

**3-** Setting `display: inline-block` to both elements

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side-nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    background: #44aac1;
  
   /*your side-nav style*/
    /*display: block;*/   /*removed*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.875rem 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

.main-section {
    height: 300px;
    background: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul class="four side-nav">
  <li><a ng-click="page = 1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="page = 4">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The parameters content will be displayed in this block by Django-->
<div class="main-section" id="content">
    main section content
</div>
```

with this strategy note that appear a litter white space between the elements and you have to handle it, there is some way to do it but is a bit cumbersome.

Anyway there are other tricks to get what you want, I hope some of these may help you.

Comment: I added the css class for side-nav. It turns out main-section didn't even exist.

I'm confused because I'm usinf foundation.css which I think was just imported. So I actually never opened it, but I was told there were some specific classes in it to do exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @Olivier I added your side-nav styles to may snippets and they still working as suppose to do, anyway can you add a working example (jsfiddle, jsbin) to see what is the problem.

Comment: The first solution worked well in the end. I just removed the height for main-section because I have a footer being added in all my templates by Django. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Olivier I'm glad to help you, and yes I just add the height to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two elements to be side by side instead of stacked on top of each other, try using `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block;`

check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kssd5uup/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a css I should have joined to this, my apologies. The display is actually even worst when I add this display: inline-block.

I edited to add the css class.